# trying to decide between asp.net and jsp

Tags: java, .net, asp.net, jsp

I am wondering if anyone can shed some lights on the situation. I am about to start a project and trying to figure out what solution is best to go with asp.net or java jsp pages

I have personally worked alot with .net and am really happy with the framework and Visual studio as IDE I find it easy to work with and there is a massive community support behind .net, i can get alot done quickly

I have not every written anything use java jsp, there will be a learning curve here , so my experience is limited here. however after seeing jira i am very impressed with its capabilities, it has changed alot since the old days ( java 1.2 ) that i used to work with, and the fact that it runs under linux is a huge plus, so i am trying to decide is the learning curve, worth the price ?

so given the situation above what would you recommended?

Thanks,
Amir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JIRA is issue and bug tracking software; it can function with any development environment, so it has no bearing on your choice of development platform.

If this is an important project or has time or budget constraints, use the platform you are familiar with that works for you.

If you have the time and inclination to learn a new platform, there is certainly merit in that. More importantly though, who will maintain this when you are not around? Will it be deployed to an environment that is already .NET-centric?

Few apps are deployed in a vacuum (unless you work for NASA), so consider all of the peopleware issues as well as the technical ones.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, I think giving time line, and lack of support of java in my own team!, it is a better decision to stick with .net

Answer (score 1):

If .Net is what you're used to and the only real advantage you care about in JSP is that it runs on Linux why not take a look at Mono?

http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Ya jira is in jsp and is a magnificent tool. But its not like you could not have developed something similar in ASP.NET.

Personally, i always go with a technology that i am confortable in. In a professional environment we have to deal with several other factors like time, teams knowledge in various technologies, deployment and maintainence.

you should concentrate on your core tech and do it in ASP.NET as you havent done anything in java before.